# Почему выдаёт ошибку runtime-error?

Tags: java, алгоритм, backend

Всем привет. Не могу понять, почему выдаёт ошибку runtime-error? Сам код работает и умеет разбивать даты на интервалы.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalField;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String type = scanner.next();
    LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse(scanner.next());
    LocalDate end = LocalDate.parse(scanner.next());
    ArrayList<Interval> intervals = new ArrayList<>();
    switch (type) {
    case "WEEK": {
      LocalDate n = start.with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 7);
      while (n.isBefore(end)) {
        intervals.add(new Interval(start, n));
        start = n.plusDays(1);
        n = n.plusWeeks(1);
      }
      intervals.add(new Interval(start, end));
      break;
    }
    case "MONTH": {
      LocalDate n = start.withDayOfMonth(start.lengthOfMonth());
      while (n.isBefore(end)) {
        intervals.add(new Interval(start, n));
        start = n.plusDays(1);
        n = n.withDayOfMonth(1).plusMonths(1);
        n = n.withDayOfMonth(n.lengthOfMonth());
      }
      intervals.add(new Interval(start, end));
      break;
    }
    case "YEAR": {
      LocalDate n = start.withDayOfYear(start.lengthOfYear());
      while (n.isBefore(end)) {
        intervals.add(new Interval(start, n));
        start = n.plusDays(1);
        n = n.withDayOfYear(1).plusYears(1);
        n = n.withDayOfYear(n.lengthOfYear());
      }
      intervals.add(new Interval(start, end));
      break;
    }
    case "QUARTER": {
      LocalDate n = start.withMonth((start.getMonthValue() / 3) * 3 + 3);
      n = n.withDayOfMonth(n.lengthOfMonth());
      while (n.isBefore(end)) {
        intervals.add(new Interval(start, n));
        start = n.plusDays(1);
        n = n.withDayOfMonth(1).plusMonths(3);
        n = n.withDayOfMonth(n.lengthOfMonth());
      }
      intervals.add(new Interval(start, end));
      break;
    }
    case "LAST_SUNDAY_OF_YEAR": {
      LocalDate n = start.withDayOfYear(start.lengthOfYear());
      while (n.getDayOfWeek() != DayOfWeek.SATURDAY)
        n = n.minusDays(1);
      while (n.isBefore(end)) {
        intervals.add(new Interval(start, n));
        start = n.plusDays(1);
        n = n.plusYears(1);
        n = n.withDayOfYear(n.lengthOfYear());
        while (n.getDayOfWeek() != DayOfWeek.SATURDAY)
          n = n.minusDays(1);
      }
      intervals.add(new Interval(start, end));
      break;
    }
    }
    System.out.println(intervals.size());
    for (Interval i : intervals) {
      i.print(System.out);
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  static class Interval {
    LocalDate start, end;

    Interval(LocalDate s, LocalDate e) {
      this.start = s;
      this.end = e;
    }

    void print(PrintStream stream) {
      stream.print(this.start + " " + this.end);
    }
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложите стек-трейс ошибки

Comment: Приложил, посмотрите.